# The Product of digit is a factor of two digit Number.No of such digits are

Tags: number-theory

[image]

**MyApproach**

I started my thought process with a 2 digit number.

$11$=$1$*$1$=$1$  which is a factor of 11

$12$=$1$*$2$=$2$ which is a factor of 12

$15$=$1$*$5$=$5$  which is a factor of 15

Similarly, I get $24$ and $36$.Therefore,My Ans is $5$.

I could not calculate though any numbers between 50 to 60,60 to 70,70 to 80,80 to 90 and 100.

> IS there any other approach I can solve this problem fast.
>
> Please guide me if I am wrong and there is another approach.

Comment: You can eliminate some options as follows. Consider the two digit number $ab$ where $a$ is the tens digit and $b$ is the units digit. This number is thus $10a + b$ . Now we want $ab | 10a+b$. Therefore $10a + b - kab = 0$ for some integer $k$. Now this can be re-written as $a(kb - 10) = b$. This means that a must divide b, this should narrow down how many numbers $(ab)$ there can be that satisfy your condition.

Comment: Specifically at most there can be $9+3+2+1+ 9 = 24$ such numbers. This eliminates option (d), also you can pretty quickly eliminate some from the first $9$ numbers $(ab)$ such that $a|b$ namely from: $11$, $12$, $13$, ... , $19$, you can check quickly, and you'll see the only ones that work from that are $11$ and $12$, $15$, so you can already get rid of 6 numbers from that list of 9. From $24$ and $26$ and $28$ you can get rid of $28$ and $26$, so we've already gotten rid of 8 from the 24. You can also shave off a few more, like $22$,$33$,$44$,etc Which means the answer can't be (c) or (d).

Comment: I have some eliminations which can be done  . They are remove from 2-digit list numbers which are prime ,perfect squares except 36  , numbers with both digits same except 11  . So now you have to check for less number of digits. Also eliminate digits which are multiples of 3 with their fist or last digit odd.

Comment: Just to add to my second comment, and make more precise 'Archis Welankar's' suggestion to remove all two-digit numbers with digits the same besides $11$, we suppose $a^2 | 10a + a = 11a$ , then $\frac{11a}{a^2} = \frac{11}{a}$ must be an integer, in other words, $a$ must divide $11$. Therefore, the only such number that does that is $a=1$. So we can already get rid of $8$ from that list of two-digit numbers with digits repeated. Leaving a maximum of $8$ as an answer, so yes, your answer of $5$ is definitely correct.

Answer (score 1):

Just leaving the elaboration of the answer in case someone finds the explanation interesting, because it's a classic question that I still see asked at institutions.
Building upon the answer by @porridgemathematics,

1. Since the two digit number is 10a+b, the value constraints of a and b are :
   1 ≤ a ≤ 9
   and
   0 ≤ b ≤ 9
2. Since a(kb−10)=b specifies that a is a factor of b, then value constraint of a further becomes :
   1 ≤ a ≤ 4 (since b is 9 or below)
3. Solve a(kb−10)=b => b=10a/(ka-1) for 1 ≤ a ≤ 4
4. If a = 1, b can only be 2 or 5. 2 choices. Ignoring repetition of digits.
5. If a = 2, b can only be 4. 1 choice.
6. If a = 3, b can only be 6. 1 choice.
7. If a = 4, b can only be 8. 1 choice.

Total 5 choices.